# removing even number of duplicates in list

Tags: prolog

I have a list of lists and I have to remove the even number of duplicates in every list.

e.g.

```
input1 : [[1,2,3],[1,4,5]], expected output : [[2,3],[4,5]]
input2 : [[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,6]], expected output : [[2,3],[4,5],[1,6]]
input 3 : [[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,6],[2,7]], expected output : [[3],[4,5],[1,6],[7]]
input 4 : [[1,2,3,1],[1,4,5]], expected output : [[2,3],[1,4,5]]
input 5 : [[1,2,3,1],[4,5]], expected output : [[2,3],[4,5]]
```

at moment, my coding is as follow:

```
duplicate([],[]).
duplicate([H|T],[[H1]|T2]):-
              \+member(H1,L),
              duplicate(T,[H1|L],T2).
duplicate([H|T],L,T2):-
              member(H,L),
              delete(H1, L, LNew),
              duplicate(T,LNew,T2).
```

Comment: What does "even number of duplicates" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I think that the element occurs two, four, six, eight, ... times.

Comment: @sandra: what if an element occurs three times: do you want to map `[1,1,1,2,3]` to `[1,2,3]`, `[1,1,1,2,3]`, or `[2,3]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the element might occur an odd number of times, but the OP only wants to remove an even number of them.

Comment: @sandra: Do you already have a strategy how to solve it, or are you simply asking to solve your homework?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, i want it to map [1,2,3]

Comment: @blacklwhite i have done that coding so far. the one up there

duplicate([H|T],[[H1]|T2]):-
              \+member(H1,L),
              duplicate(T,[H1|L],T2).
duplicate([H|T],L,T2):-
              member(H,L),
              delete(H1, L, LNew),
              duplicate(T,LNew,T2).